# Apache server compression and leverage browse caching problems

Tags: php, linux, apache, caching, compression

My apache web server admin, claims that,the server supports deflate gzip compression and for reason, shows environment variable `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate` to me.

I know there is two method for compression. method one, is in PHP level, using `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` and second method is in server level, using `.htaccess` with some commands in it, like this one

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css`

`<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">`

`SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`

`</FilesMatch>`

I check both compression method with some tools like [page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)

First method works for me properly, but second method does not work.
I'd like to use server side compression method, and i found many people in the net have problem like me.
Server admin just claims `everything is ok from his point of view and gzip/deflate is active`

I have other problem with `leverage browse caching` which google recommend web masters to using it.

just like compression, there are standard codes for `.htaccess` file, like this one

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>`

`ExpiresActive On`

`ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"`

`ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"`

`ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"`

`ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"`

`ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"`

`ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"`

`ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"`

`ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"`

`ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"`

`ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"`

`</IfModule>`

unfortunately, it does not work like compression.
our apache server version is 2.2.20.

I don't know how prove to server admin, which there is something wrong with server installation.

perhaps it's a bug of this version of apache.
i am really confuse, specially when i understand there are some people in the world, which have exactly same problems like me and there is no reply.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation: the Apache server may be configured to **not allow overrides** (i.e., changes in a local .htaccess file). See the [Apache AllowOverride docs page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) to see if that may be the issue here.

In my case my shared web host doesn't have mod_gzip or mod_deflate installed, so I use the same PHP method you mentioned and it works pretty well.

I recommend using **[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)** as a quick method to test both compression and expires settings. (It's also an easy way to share results with your server admin.)

For example, to check for **compression**, include the "--compress" option, and look for a response header "Content-Encoding: gzip":

```
$ curl --head --compress http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.36
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2011 03:15:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Dec 2011 00:54:40 GMT
ETag: "0c85c47fbc4cc1:0"
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

You can also check for the working **Expires** header:

```
$ curl --head http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/1/80x60/sss3.gif
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2011 01:34:59 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Expires: Sun, 19 Dec 2021 01:34:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Dec 2009 16:54:28 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3059
Content-Type: image/gif
Age: 524606
Connection: keep-alive
Server: YTS/1.20.9
```

Comment: Thanks..very nice...i did not know about curl!...i downloaded it and it works for your example very nice but unfortunately when i use it like `curl --compress http://www.mysite.com` it returns `406 not acceptable` error!.... i created new question for my new error. please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653271/curl-command-return-http-1-1-406-not-acceptable-error)...but there is not useful reply... what's the hell these problems?!... and who is the redeemer?!...you can Brian...i know you are the man Brian.