# curl command return http/1.1 406 not acceptable error

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl, compression

I am using below command line curl for knowing if my site supports compressing and caching

`curl --head --compress http://www.mysite.com`

it returns the following result

```
Http://1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2011 07:41:32 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset-iso-8859-1
```

what do you think about the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `curl` to check if your website supports compression and caching. They're both headers sent by Apache.

Comment: it does not support compression . admin server claims it does and i have to prove him

Comment: Why not just probe php.ini? There are functions available for it, like `ini_get`.

Comment: How can i use `ini_get` for knowing and proving that the server does not support compression?

Answer (score 37):

In some case I had, faking the agent solved this problem, by using:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/4.0"
```

Similarly using `libcurl C-API`:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
```

Comment: I had to use the full agent string "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", "Mozilla/5.0" didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: The faking agent worked exactly as provided, for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the HTTP/1.1 standard:

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
>   response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the accept headers sent in the request.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity
>   containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s)
>   from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.

So drop the --head and you *should* see whats wrong.

The 406 may just be what is proving you right - the server doesn't support compression. :)

Comment: when i drop the `--head` it shows me the following lines
`<html></head>
<title>406 not acceptable </title>
</head></body>
<h1>not acceptable</h1>
.
.
`
i am using utf-8 characters in title and h1 tag too

Comment: I thought it would show more then just that. Anyway, 406 basically means "you asked for something I can't give you". `curl --compress` sends `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` - apparently your server cannot serve that.

In short: This response proves that your sysadmin is wrong, the server does not support compression. You can use curl's -v flag for more verbose output, inclusing the request-headers. That may help convince your sysadmin.

Comment: when i use phpinfo() for my site, it shows me this variable environment `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING   gzip,delate`