# Does curl require some server end configuration?

Tags: curl, http-status-code-406

I am trying to use a windows 7 batch file to download a files from my website.

This command works :

```
curl -v http://jsonlint.com/c/images/logo_arc90.png > j.jpg
```

This one does not :

```
curl -v http://starlords3k.com/images/star_1001.png > s.jpg
```

I get the following error:  HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Is there something I need to configure on the server to allow the download?

OR What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+406

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653271/curl-command-return-http-1-1-406-not-acceptable-error

Comment: None of those seem to apply.

Comment: faking the User-Agent to Mozilla fixed the issue: `curl  http://starlords3k.com/images/star_1001.png > s.jpg -A "Mozilla"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faking the User-Agent to Mozilla fixed the issue:

```
curl http://starlords3k.com/images/star_1001.png > s.jpg -A "Mozilla"
```